# Show that a function is injective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function $C^{1}$ such that $|f'(t)|\leq k < 1 ~ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\phi(x,y)= (x+f(y),y+f(x))$. Show that $\phi$ is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\phi(x,y)=\phi(u,v).$ Thus we have

$$|x-u|=|f(v)-f(y)|\le k |v-y|$$ and

$$|y-v|=|f(u)-f(x)|\le k|x-u|.$$ Since $k<1$ this is only possible if $x=u$ and $y=v.$ This shows injectivity.